# What are some tools to replace conventional performance testing (using stopwatch) of Java EE Spring projects in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, performance, spring, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

Currently, I'm testing performance of a web application using stopwatch, which appears to be a rather archaic method. So, I would really like, if someone enlightens me about the possible alternatives: tools that will let me measure the time difference between request and response, total time to load a page etc. I'm working on Eclipse, on a project based on Spring Framework.(A free eclipse plugin/app should be great! Something like TPTP maybe).

Comment: [VMware vFabric tc Server (Developer Edition) with Spring Insight](http://www.vmware.com/products/application-platform/vfabric-tcserver/overview.html) ([1](http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/6.0/devedition/images/recent_activity_screen_with_labels.png)) ([2](http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric5/topic/com.vmware.vfabric.tc-server.2.6/operations/images/dashboard.png))

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do the performance testing on the server, rather than a local machine, because you will be doing a lot of configs on the server to optimize performance, which will be non-existent on local. Also, the Data sources would take a longer time to respond back to a local machine than to a datacenter machine, creating lags which aren't attributed to the code.

And the testing front, I would suggest to go for [Rational Performance Tester](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/products/performancetester/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Jmeter

http://jmeter.apache.org/

JMeter may be used to test performance both on static and dynamic resources (files, Servlets, Perl scripts, Java Objects, Data Bases and Queries, FTP Servers and more). It can be used to simulate a heavy load on a server, network or object to test its strength or to analyze overall performance under different load types.